# Save a paragraph in localStorage so when the page reloads it displays unless it gets deleted

Tags: javascript, html, dom, local-storage

how could I save an element in localStorage that it has been displayed once a button execute a function and after reload is kept unless it is removed

```html
<div class="newd">
  <button class="create" >create task</button>
</div>
```

```
let ids1 = document.getElementById('ids')
let ids2 = document.getElementById('ids2')
let ids3 = document.getElementById('ids3')
let newd = document.getElementsByClassName('newd')
let buttonCreateTask = document.getElementsByClassName('create')

function createTask() {

  let paro         = document.createElement('p')
  let remove       = document.createElement('button')
  remove.innerHTML = 'X'
  paro.innerText   = ids1.value + '\n' + ids2.value + '\n' + ids3.value
  paro.appendChild(remove)
  remove.onclick = function() {
    paro.remove()
  }
  if (ids1.value !== '') {
    if (ids2.value !== '') {
      if (ids3.value !== '') {
        newd[0].appendChild(paro)
        ids1.value = ''
        ids2.value = ''
        ids3.value = ''
        //tried to store it like this
        localStorage.setItem('saved', newd[0])
      } else {
        console.log('missing date')
      }
    } else {
      console.log('missing description')
    }
  } else {
    console.log('missing value')
  }
  return paro
}

buttonCreateTask[0].addEventListener('click', createTask)

let saved = localStorage.getItem('saved')
if (saved) {
  document.body.appendChild(saved)
}
```

`buttonCreateTask` generates the task once clicked but if I reload, the element created disappears. I tried doing `document.body.appendChild(saved)` but that gives me

> Uncaught TypeError: failed to execute 'appendchild' on 'node' parameter 1 is not of type 'node'.

How could I keep it using localStorage?

Comment: isn't there a `<form>...`  on this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the `innerHTML` of the element in `localStorage` and use event delegation for handling the remove button. However, it would be best to rethink the design at this point.

```js
// ...
let prevContent = localStorage.getItem('saved');
if (prevContent) newd[0].innerHTML = prevContent;
newd[0].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (e.target.matches('button.remove')) {
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
        localStorage.setItem('saved',  newd[0].innerHTML)
    }
});
let buttonCreateTask = document.querySelector('.create');
buttonCreateTask.addEventListener('click', createTask);
function createTask (){ 
    let paro = document.createElement('p')
    let remove = document.createElement('button')
    remove.classList.add('remove');
    remove.innerHTML = 'X' 
    paro.innerText = ids1.value + '\n' + ids2.value + '\n' + ids3.value 
    paro.appendChild(remove)
    newd[0].appendChild(paro)
    ids1.value = ''
    ids2.value = ''
    ids3.value = ''
    localStorage.setItem('saved',  newd[0].innerHTML)
    return paro
}
```

Comment: See the code working here: https://jsfiddle.net/20t5fzvy/

Comment: it does but that makes my `createTask`  function stop creating more than one tasks as  `buttonCreateTask`  is clicked

Comment: @willd The button works just fine in the JSFiddle link above. You may not have changed all the code to match my answer. In particular, you must select the button element **after** setting the `innerHTML` when loading the previous content.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the value you giving to the variable "paro" and when you want to show it again you can create a new element and use the stored data as it´s value or "innerText".

Hope it helps!

Comment: I will try to give you the exact code tomorrow if you need it.

Comment: That would be really appreciate it! thanks.